# after upgrading from vagrant 1.8.1 to 1.84 not all machines start by default

Tags: vagrant, salt-stack

After i have upgraded the vagrant from 1.8.1 to 1.8.4, when i issue vagrant up command, only first machine starts, while second only will only start if I issue "vagrant up vmname" command. I do not have anything regarding autostart and i assume that both should start, but they dont...
code below:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.define :webserver do |webserver|
    webserver.vm.box = BASE_IMAGE_NAME 
    webserver.vm.box_url = BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_REF
    webserver.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.2.0.10"
    webserver.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 80, host: 8880
    webserver.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 443, host: 4443
    webserver.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 8080, host: 8888
    webserver.vm.synced_folder VAGRANT_SYNC_PATH, TOMCAT_INSTALL_PATH  
    webserver.vm.synced_folder WEBSERVER_PATH, "/srv/salt/" 
    webserver.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
      vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
    end 
     webserver.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
         sudo hostname web1.domain.com
     SHELL
     webserver.vm.provision "salt" do |salt|
         salt.masterless = true
         salt.minion_config = WEBSERVER_MINION_PATH
        ###salt.minion_config = "/srv/salt/minion"
         salt.run_highstate = true
         salt.colorize = true
         #salt.verbose = true
     end
 end

 config.vm.define :redis do |redis|
   redis.vm.box = BASE_IMAGE_NAME
   redis.vm.box_url = BASE_IMAGE_ARTIFACTORY_REF
   redis.vm.network "private_network", ip: "10.2.0.20"
   redis.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 6379, host: 6379
   redis.vm.synced_folder VAGRANT_SYNC_PATH, TOMCAT_INSTALL_PATH
   redis.vm.synced_folder REDIS_PATH, "/srv/salt/" 
   redis.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |vb|
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", "512"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--cpus", "2"]
   end 
    redis.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
        sudo hostname redis1.domain.com
    SHELL
    redis.vm.provision "salt" do |salt|
        salt.masterless = true
        salt.minion_config = REDIS_MINION_PATH
        #salt.minion_config = "/srv/salt/minion"
        salt.run_highstate = true
        salt.colorize = true
        #salt.verbose = true
    end
end
end
```

here is the output with salt commented out:

```
C:\vagrantfiles\MOBILEWEB\WINDOWS\TOMCAT-REDIS>vagrant up
 Bringing machine 'webserver' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
 ==> webserver: Importing base box 'vagrant-centos7-base'...
 ==> webserver: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
 ==> webserver: Setting the name of the VM: TOMCAT-REDIS_webserver_1468231810504_5980 ==> webserver: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
 ==> webserver: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
 webserver: Adapter 1: nat
 webserver: Adapter 2: hostonly
 ==> webserver: Forwarding ports...
webserver: 80 (guest) => 8880 (host) (adapter 1)
webserver: 443 (guest) => 4443 (host) (adapter 1)
webserver: 8080 (guest) => 8888 (host) (adapter 1)
webserver: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
 ==> webserver: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
 ==> webserver: Booting VM...
 ==> webserver: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
webserver: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
webserver: SSH username: vagrant
webserver: SSH auth method: private key
webserver: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
webserver: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
webserver: Warning: Remote connection disconnect. Retrying...
webserver:
webserver: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace

webserver: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
webserver:
webserver: Inserting generated public key within guest...
webserver: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
webserver: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...

 ==> webserver: Machine booted and ready!
 ==> webserver: Checking for guest additions in VM...
 ==> webserver: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
 ==> webserver: Mounting shared folders...
webserver: /vagrant => C:/vagrantfiles/MOBILEWEB/WINDOWS/TOMCAT-REDIS
webserver: /srv/salt => C:/vagrantfiles/vgsalt/webserver
webserver: /opt/apache-tomcat-8.0.33/webapps => C:/vagrantsync
  ==> webserver: Running provisioner: shell...
webserver: Running: inline script

  C:\vagrantfiles\MOBILEWEB\WINDOWS\TOMCAT-REDIS>
```

Comment: There has been no change on this between 1.8.1 and 1.8.4 - I have config with 2 or 4 machines and everything runs fine. whats the output of `vagrant up` ? try to remove your salt provisioning to see if it would come from there

Comment: thank you for the response, when i do vagrant up, it literally just brings up the first VM and stops.

Comment: output with salt added, it still does not book the second box

Comment: salt provisioning does not even run .. try remove the shell provisioning, weird. I run a config with centos71 and 2 vms, no issue; there must be something, try starting with the redis machine first

Comment: sorry forgot to mention, this is after commenting out the salt provisioninig. I will try switching them around and post update

Comment: and if you run `vagrant status` after ? it just say that web server is running and nothing on redis ?

Comment: intresting enough, it looks like vagrant recognized it, just didnt create: C:\vagrantfiles\TOMCAT-REDIS>vagrant status
Current machine states:

webserver                 running (virtualbox)
redis                     not created (virtualbox)

This environment represents multiple VMs. The VMs are all listed
above with their current state. For more information about a specific
VM, run `vagrant status NAME`.

Comment: really I don't know .. I would try to remove line by line until to find if something wrong in the config (I copied your config without salt and it was working for me so really I don't see anything wrong)